# Preg match text in php between html tags

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

Hello I would like to use preg_match in PHP to parse the "Desired text" out of the following from a html document

```
<p class="review"> Desired text </p>
```

Ordinarily I would use simple_html_dom for such things but on this occasion it cannot be used (the above element doesn't appear in every desired div tag so I'm forced to use this approach to keep track of exactly when it doesn't appear and then adjust my array from simple_html_dom accordingly).

Anyway, this would solve my problem.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
preg_match("'<p class=\"review\">(.*?)</p>'si", $source, $match);
if($match) echo "result=".$match[1];
```

Comment: Isn't this likely to overmatch?  See my answer below.

Comment: It won't overmatch because of lazy quantification. `.*?` will grab as less as possible, while `.*` would grab as much as possible.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to return multiple matches then need to use preg_match_all(). You then loop through the second result group ($match[1]) to get just the content between tags.

```
$source = "<p class=\"review\"> Desired text1 </p>".
"<p class=\"review\"> Desired text2 </p>".
"<p class=\"review\"> Desired text3 </p>";


    preg_match_all("'<p class=\"review\">(.*?)</p>'si", $source, $match);

    foreach($match[1] as $val)
    {
        echo $val."<br>";


    }

Outputs:

Desired text1
Desired text2
Desired text3
```

Answer (score 7):

What if the string you're matching has multiple lines and is:

```
<p class="review"> Desired text1 </p>
<p class="review"> Desired text2 </p>
<p class="review"> Desired text3 </p>
```

That pattern would match once, and the match would be everything in the string.

I think a better pattern is:

```
"'<p class=\"review\">([^<]*)</p>'si"
```

Comment: yes, thanks, i've been trying stuff for the past 2 hours and I finally realised that the stocks are being displayed with JavaScript, after the page is loading :((( so yey, that's why the script was not working  thanks all