# Count regular expression matches in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to count a group of regular expressions in a dynamically loaded `<div>` that I've loaded using the load() function. I also need to resize this `<div>` to the longest line of characters in it. Is there a way to achieve this? I've tried searching around and can't find anything, not even on SO. I should mention that the expression I am testing for is:

```
Sat Mar 12 12:45:38 PST 2011
```

Using this regex:

```
if ($('#result').text().match(/[A-Za-z]{3}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}/))
```

Comment: Did you try Google? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str="The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var patt1=/ain/gi;  //noticed the g.  g will enable match of all occurance, and without it it'll only match the first occurance
console.log(str.match(patt1).length);  //4 matched
```

JavaScript match regex function returns an array so you can basically do a length on that array and get the size of the matched elements.  Make sure you are using the `g` in RegEx to search all occurance

Based on your RegEx you can do the following:

```
$('#result').text().match(/[A-Za-z]{3}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}/g).length //this should give you the total count of occurance
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can resize the `<div>` dynamically? Also, I need to obtain the contents between two matches. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: @malfy you can use javascript to set the width and height of the div. are you attempting to get the content between tags? something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags

Comment: I just want to resize the `<div>` to the width of the largest string. And I don't want to use PHP for this either, I need to know the Javascript functions and methods.

Comment: If there is no match it will give JS exception right?

Answer (score 1):

kjy112 gave you your answer. Like that answer clarified, this isn't really jQuery, but Javascript RegEx's (so maybe that was throwing off your search).

If that regex turns out to be slow-- which it might if you return many dates-- you can just count some nique component, such as just the years:

```
$('#result').text().match(/\d{4}/).length
```

Answer (score 0):

Malfy,

3 ways to get the width of a string come to mind.  I'll go over those first, then how to get the length of the longest.  It looks like others have addressed the regex.

```
1) (fastest)
```

If only the text itself needs to be a certain width, not the div, then you can use white-space:nowrap to ensure the text remains the full width.

```
$('div.someClass').css('whiteSpace','nowrap');




2) (slowest)
```

If you need the pixel width of a string to set another div's width, one way to do that is to create an element containing that string and use the css property above.  Example:

```
var yourString = 'your string';
// create a div containing your string
var $tempDiv = jQuery('<div style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap">'+jQuery.trim(yourString)+'</div>').appendTo('body');
$newDiv = <your new div, however you're creating it>;
// set the width of the new div to the width of the temp div
$newDiv.width($tempDiv.width());
// and clean up;
$tempDiv.remove();
//repeat as necessary




3) (quite fast too)
```

Alternately, if you're sure you'll be using a monospace font (courier, consolas, etc).  There's a much faster way. Save the width of a single character and multiplying it by the length of each new text string. That way you aren't writing a new element each time.  For example:

```
var $tempDiv = $('<div style="visibility:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">z</div>').appendTo('body');
//(any character will work. z is just for example); 
var reusableCharacterWidth=$tempDiv.width();
$tempDiv.remove();

var firstString = your string';
// set the width of your first div
$newDiv.width(reusableCharacterWidth*firstString.length);
var nextString = 'your next string';
// set the width of your next div
$nextNewDiv.width(reusableCharacterWidth*nextString.length);
```

(note: you may want to use $.trim() on the strings just in case)

To get the longest string:

```
var longestLineLength,
    yourText= 'your text here';
function getLongestLineLength(lines){
    var oneLineLength,
        longest=0,
        linesArray = lines.split('\n');
    for(var i=0,len=linesArray.length;i<len;i++){
        oneLineLength=linesArray[i].length;
        longest=oneLineLength>longest?oneLineLength:longest;
    }
  return longest;
}
longestLineLength = getLongestLineLength(yourText);
```

Cheers!

Adam

Comment: Your final solution was good, but slightly wrong, I had to modify your code, as there longest was undefined and some variable names were mixed up. Also, now that I have the longest line in characters (would have been easy enough for me to do), the real question is how do I set my `<div>` to be that length? px won't work well, nor will em, or ex, or pt. Also, I think the method of creating a new `<div>` to fill in an old one, is a bad practice.

Comment: You're right. The last solution is funky.  That's what I get for posting near 1am without testing the code first. ;)  I'll fix it in a sec.

Comment: Regarding "How do I set my div to be that length?".. I'm unsure how to answer that.  If you aren't using px, or em, ex, pts, what's left.. maybe %?

Can you give me an example of what success looks like from a user's perspective?

Re good/bad practices: My hope was to provide a starting point.  In infrequent situations, working solutions are usually good enough for me.  If you know better practices to improve on these with, great!

Comment: It's simple. Suppose we have a string, aaaaaa, the `<div>` outline  should fit like this: |aaaaaa|

Comment: Divs are block elements and take up 100% width by default since they're intended to separate vertical page sections.  Spans are inline elements and auto-resize like you're looking for.  If you want divs to do that, you'll have to manually set their widths like I mentioned above.  This may help: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssspacing.html

Comment: The problem with spans is that they seem to stop after every paragraph.