# Match text between HTML class tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I got the following HTML code:

```
<ul class='ips'>my_content</ul>
```

Now, how can I `preg_match_all` this, to match only the `my_content` text?

I was trying answers from this question: [Preg match text in php between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags) but modifying the regex result in selecting the whole code including HTML tags.

Comment: See [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1396314)

Comment: I dont want to include any additional PHP libraries.

Comment: @Rusco Do you have libxml? If you do then you have `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Yes, I do. But I havent found any example on how to process my problem using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @Rusco Have you ever worked with Javascript? The function calls are essentially the same. [And docs are here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: @Rusco Also, you do realize that text traditionally isn't found within a `<ul>`. Typically the unordered list has many `<li>` children which hold text and other DOM elements.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Its not that, here I have to grep the ul with the `ips` class, while in the `DOMDocument` I can only use `getElementById('ul')` and then I will have to loop trough all `ul's` to see if a class name is `ips` - this is kinda memory waste.

Comment: @Rusco The problem is HTML is not regular. You need a library like xmllib to handle the HTML parsing for you. See here if you don't believe me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I guess you mean those native XML extensions - DOM, XMLReader. Could you give me an example on how can I match an element WITH specified class?

Comment: @Rusco `foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $node) { if($node->attributes->getNamedItem('class') == 'ips') { stuff(); }}`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I've tested your example and it never runs the `stuff();` , I got ul with the class `ips` loaded in the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will work for matching between the tags.

It will match:

```
<ul class='ips'>...
```

With single quotes and double quotes.

```
$string = "<ul class='ips'>my_content</ul>";
preg_match_all('/[^>]class=["\']ips[\'"]*>(.*?)<\//',
           $string,
           $matches,
           PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

If you don't care if it is a div, ul or etc, remove the `<ul` and `ul>` from the regex pattern.

Response from above:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <ul class="ips">my_content</ul>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => my_content
    )

)
```

Comment: I wrote that I need to match content of a specified class tag. The example you gave will match any tag element, and not only with class `ips`.

Comment: Gives an error message: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier ']'`

Comment: @sixeightzero Seems like you have some unescaped quotes in your regex. Make sure to always escape quotes and backslashes in regex.

Comment: Thanks.. i use regextester.com to test my regex's on the fly. always forgetting to escape the quotes. :(

Comment: Its not that, as I've escaped the quotes, also updated my script with your edit and still gives the same message.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, i dropped the delimiters when editing the post going back. Added them back and tested well.

Comment: Well, I got `$string = '<ul class=\'ips\'>my_content</ul>';` and `$matches` is returning an empty array. I guess its caused by an double quote there `class="ips"`, it should be `class='ips'` instead (with single quote). Isnt there a way so it would work with the single quotes?

Comment: The above is designed to look for ' or ", in the event you use both syntax's. What version PCRE libraries do you have installed? I pasted the above code and results that work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this RegEx to allow variations:

```
/[^>]class\s*=\s*["\'].*ips.*[\'"].*>/
```

- spaces before or after equals sign
- multiple class names in one class attribute
- multiple attributes after the class attribute