# php regex - remove empty a tag around string

Tags: php, regex, optimization

I have the following string that is part of a larger string which I *think* I'll need to perform a `preg_replace` on.

> `&nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About Us</a>`

The larger string is:

> `<a href='http://ecolution.dev'>Home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About
>   Us</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;Meet the Directors`

Now I can match the first string easily with something like `/&nbsp;.*?<\/a>\s+/` - that works fine.

What I actually need to do is remove the `&nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>` from the string and also the `</a>`. So that plain text is left in the larger string.

I could remove the 2 parts separately in multiple `preg_replace` calls but that doesn't seem like the best option to me at all.

Is there a way to get any text between `&nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>` and `</a>` and then output it as plain text so that `&nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About Us</a>` simply becomes `About Us`?

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned this earlier. This is a dynamically created breadcrumb system inside ExpressionEngine. Some entries have empty `href`, so `<a href=''>abc</a>` and those entries need to have their `a` tags removed, hence why trying to match the characters/strings above so that it's just plain text

> `<a href='http://ecolution.dev'>Home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About
>   Us</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;Meet the Directors`

would become

> `<a href='http://ecolution.dev'>Home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;About Us
>   &nbsp;>&nbsp;Meet the Directors`

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to convert those `&nbsp;` and then use some HTML parser. Have fun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preg match text in php between html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags)

Comment: @Egg not so sure as this string is populated dynamically. Let me edit to add more info to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the tags for any anchor link with an empty href: `<a href=''>text</a>`:

```
$html = "<a href='http://ecolution.dev'>Home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About Us</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;Meet the Directors";
$result = preg_replace("/<a href=''>(.*?)<\/a>/", "$1", $html);
// Result = "<a href='http://ecolution.dev'>Home</a> &nbsp;>&nbsp;About Us &nbsp;>&nbsp;Meet the Directors"
```

Using `'$1'` in the second parameter of `preg_replace` allows us to put back in the first matched string (from our first parameter of `preg_replace`).

Comment: So this won't actually remove the a tags, this will just extract the text? I'd need to replace the string that is wrapped in the empty a tag with the string extracted

Comment: I'm confused. You asked "is there a way to get any text and then output it as plain text so that `&nbsp;>&nbsp;<a href=''>About Us</a>` simply becomes `About Us`. With my example, you get that in `$match[2]`, so `$html = $match[2]` if you want to replace the string with the text.

Comment: That's probably me badly wording my question, while you are right, I would need to replace it in the strings place, not extract it and use it elsewhere. Let me update the question properly