# preg_match escape for backslashes

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I'm trying to get the value from my HTML SPAN element:

```
<span class=\"date-display-single\">1462732200</span>
```

I've tried the below mentioned approach but it seems that there is an issue with the backslahes used in my above mentioned HTML element.

I came to know that using [4 backslashes](http://www.developwebsites.net/match-backslash-preg_match-php/) can help me, but it didn't! Any other approach to achieve the value inside the HTML element mentioned above. i.e. **1462732200**

```
<span class=\"date\-display\-single\">(.*?)<\/span>
```

Comment: I've exposed that HTML element in JSON, hence its like that.

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fCE but you should perhaps use a different method than regex when parsing html?

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse HTML via `preg_match()`, use

[PHP DOM Document Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$html = '<span class=\"date-display-single\">1462732200</span>';
// a new dom object 
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
// load the html into the object ***/ 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
//discard white space 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$hTwo= $dom->getElementsByTagName('span'); // here u use your desired tag
echo $hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is another post that may give some insight into this problem:

[Preg match text in php between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags)

2. Another alternative could also be using an actual parser to parse your data such as simplehtmldom. Just throwing it out there, as I know that depending on the situation, it can help a great deal

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

A third (or fourth, depending on how you count) is to use strpos.

```
$str = '1111<span class=\"date-display-single\">1462732200</span>22222';
$pos = strpos($str, '<span class=\"date-display-single\">');
$pos2= strpos($str, '</span>');

$str2 = strip_tags(substr($str, $pos,$pos2));
echo $str2;
```

But Object manipulator gave you the best answer. Go with that.