# extract a protion of html file

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I have used dompdf to create pdf file, I have used a portion of the html file ie between  to generate pdf . (cut & pasted manual way)

since I have a valid pdf out put now, I want to further automate the process,

I want to copy all contents between  tables

```
<table> </table>
```

to a file, would like to know  what would be possible options in php.
any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Where can we help with a problem you have run into? We will not write all the code for you, you need to provide an attempt and expected input/outputs.

Comment: What is the source(wheres it from) of the HTML file?

Comment: the html file is the output of a php code , I have used    following code                        <?php // Start output buffering
ob_start();
// run code in x.php file
include "itpreviewsheet.php";
// saving captured output to file
file_put_contents('fileame.htm', ob_get_contents());
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();    ................  to get output file in html format

Comment: How do I extract all content between <table>....</table > , any clue or tips will of great help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @ArvindGK Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex, instead use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

The following class will extract out the content between any element. So load your html from your file, or just pass it the contents of `ob_get_contents()`

```
<?php 

class DOMExtract extends DOMDocument
{
    private $source;
    private $dom;

    public function __construct()
    {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $this->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $this->formatOutput = true;
    }

    public function setSource($source)
    {
        $this->source = $source;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getInnerHTML($tag, $id=null, $nodeValue = false)
    {
        if (empty($this->source)) {
            throw new Exception('Error: Missing $this->source, use setSource() first');
        }

        $this->loadHTML($this->source);
        $tmp = $this->getElementsByTagName($tag);
        $ret = null;
        foreach ($tmp as $v) {
            if ($id !== null) {
                $attr = explode('=', $id);
                if ($v->getAttribute($attr[0]) == $attr[1]) {
                    if ($nodeValue == true) {
                        $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                    } else {
                        $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if ($nodeValue == true) {
                    $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                } else{
                    $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                }
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    protected function innerHTML($dom)
    {
        $ret = "";
        foreach ($dom->childNodes as $v) {
            $tmp = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp->appendChild($tmp->importNode($v, true));
            $ret .= trim($tmp->saveHTML());
        }
        return $ret;
    }

}

$html = '
<h3>HTML Table Example</h3>
<div>
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMExtract();
$dom->setSource($html);

echo '
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%">',
    //match and return only tables inner content with id=customers
    $dom->getInnerHTML('table', 'id=customers'), 
    //match all tables inner content
    //$dom->getInnerHTML('table'), 
'</table>';
```

https://3v4l.org/OkbQW

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%"><tr><th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This
To Extract Data between tags try this code
Here `$source` will be your complete html code. And `$match` will be the data extracted between tags.

Code:

`preg_match("'<table>(.*?)</table>'si", $source, $match);
if($match) echo "result=".$match[1];`

Reference: [Preg match text in php between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586779/preg-match-text-in-php-between-html-tags)